# Lighttpd domain redirection

Tags: lighttpd

I would like to redirect domains on HTTP/HTTPS:

```
http://old.com -> https://new.com
https://old.com -> https://new.com
```

I have to specify the SSL key/certificate for the old domain but I'm not sure where I have to place these directives:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/etc/pki/tls/private/new.com.pem"
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/new.com.crt"
}

$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "old.com|new.com" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://new.com:443/$1" )
  }
}
```

I was trying to add the code below but Lighttpd reports configuration errors:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
$HTTP["host"] =~ "old.com" {
url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://new.com:443/$1" )
   }
ssl.engine = "enable"
ssl.pemfile = "/etc/pki/tls/private/old.com.pem"
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/old.com.crt"

}
```

Comment: What configuration errors are reported?  Did you add a whole new `$SERVER["socket"] == ":443"` instead of modifying the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

There can be only one certificate per port.

The possible solutions are:

1. You get another IP address and specify the old certificate here.
2. You get a multi domain certificate (which is valid for both the old and the new domain name).

Comment: Actually, TLS Server Name Indication [is supported in lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_SSL#Server-Name-Indication-SNI).  One of these days, there will be little enough Windows XP in the world that we'll be able to use it - but for the asker's needs, Windows XP support may be unneeded.

Comment: @ShaneMadden yes, somewhat true... However I would not deploy it today.